# Solr Delta Import Query is deleting everything in the

Tags: solr

I am trying to get a delta import query working for my solr schema. When I do a full import the solr index gets populated correctly. However, when I try and do the delta import, it looks like it processes normally - and gives the following result in the solr gui:

```
Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 0 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
Requests: 1, Fetched: 0, Skipped: 0, Processed: 0
```

This is correct, as the database should have no updates since the full query.

However, when I do a full query of the core after the delta update, it shows all the documents are gone, and the core is empty! All of this I am doing through the solr web admin gui.

Here is the delta import handler config file:

```
<entity name="episode" query="select episode_id from db.episode"
  deltaQuery="select episode_id from db.episode where last_modified &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'"
  deltaImportQuery="select episode_id from db.episode where episode_id = '${dih.delta.episode_id}'">
</entity>
```

Here is the relevant stuff in the schema file:

```
<fields>
    <field name='episode_id' indexed="true" stored="true" type='int' required="true"/>
</fields>
```

And here is the DIH stuff in my solrconfig.xml:

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/lib/" regex="mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar" />
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">episodeDIHconfigfile.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Any ideas why this would be happening? I thought the delta query would just add to the index, and not just delete everything! All help much appreciated...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you say you're using the admin gui, I'm going to guess that you have that little "clean" checkbox ticked, which means your import starts with the `clean` flag set to true. Uncheck that box and try again.

If you set `clean` to true, the entire index is wiped before indexing begins. Very useful for full-imports, but obviously not for deltas!

Comment: Genius TMBT! You are a genius!

Comment: @TMBT I have same configuration but all 0 in response Requests: 0, Fetched: 0, Skipped: 0, Processed: 0, Please let me know the reason. If you want I can post the question,

Comment: @Kamini This could be due to one or more problems. You'll need to post a question.

Comment: @TMBT .I have added new question .Please find link as below-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881185/solr-delta-import-query-is-not-working

Comment: Why the hell this is actually not ignored for delta, nor the checkbox in the gui is not disabled for delta?