# Solr delta import Query exception

Tags: solr

THis is my db configuration file , I am able to full import properly 
but getting problem to 
**delta import**

there is two exception

1. datasource exception related to mysql
2. DHI

> ```
> <dataConfig>
> <dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://10.30.2.32:3306/artemis" batchSize="-1"
> ```
>
> user="username" password="password" />
>
> ```
> <document>
> <entity name="job" pk="job_id"
>
>  query="SELECT * FROM job"
>  deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM job WHERE job_id = '${dataimporter.delta.id}'"
>  deltaQuery="SELECT job_id FROM job WHERE updated_date > convert_tz('${dataimporter.last_index_time}','+00:00','-05:30')">
>
> <field column="job_id" name="jobId"/>
> <field column="keywords" name="keywords"/>
> <field column="speaciality" name="speaciality"/>
> <field column="salary_min" name="salaryMin"/>
> <field column="salary_max" name="salaryMax"/>
> <field column="created_date" name="createdDate"/>
> <field column="updated_date" name="updatedDate"/>
> <field column="updated_date" name="updatedDate"/>  
> <field column="experience_from" name="experienceFrom"/>
> <field column="experience_to" name="experienceTo"/>
> <field column="job_title" name="jobTitle"/> 
>
> <entity name="city" 
>
>  query="SELECT * FROM city where city_id ='${job.place_of_interview_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select city_id from city where updated_date >convert_tz('${dataimporter.last_index_time}','+00:00','-05:30')"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select job_id from job where place_of_interview_id='${city.city_id}'" 
>  >
>
>
>
> <field column="name" name="city"/>
>
> <entity name="district" 
>  query="SELECT * FROM district where district_id='${city.district_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select district_id from district where updated_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select city_id from city where district_id='${district.district_id}'"
>  >  
>   <field column="name" name="district"/>
>
>  <entity name="state" 
>  query="SELECT * FROM state where state_id='${district.state_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select state_id from state where updated_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select district_id from district where state_id='${state.state_id}'"
>  >  
>   <field column="name" name="state"/>
>
>  <entity name="country" 
>  query="SELECT * FROM country where country_id='${state.country_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select country_id from country where updated_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select state_id from state where country_id='${country.country_id}'"
>  >  
>   <field column="name" name="country"/>
>
>  <entity name="region" 
>  query="SELECT * FROM region where region_id='${country.region_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select region_id from region where updated_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select country_id from country where region_id='${region.region_id}'"
>  >  
>   <field column="name" name="region"/>
>
> </entity>   
>
>
> </entity> 
>
>
> </entity> 
>
>
> </entity>
>
> </entity>
>
>  <entity name="jobFunction" 
>  query="SELECT * FROM job_function where job_function_id='${job.job_function_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select job_function_id from job_function where updated_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select job_id from job where job_function_id='${jobFunction.job_function_id}'"
>  >  
>   <field column="name" name="jobFunction"/>
>
>  <entity name="jobCategory" 
>  query="SELECT * FROM master_data where id='${jobFunction.job_category_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select id from master_data where updated_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select job_function_id from job_function where job_category_id='${jobCategory.id}'"
>  >  
>
>  <field column="name" name="jobCategory"/>
>
> </entity>  
>
> </entity>  
>
>
>
>  <entity name="companyName" 
>  query="SELECT * FROM employer where employer_id='${job.employer_id}'"
>  deltaQuery="select employer_id from employer where updated_date > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"
>  parentDeltaQuery="select job_id from job where employer_id='${companyName.employer_id}'"
>  >  
>
>  <field column="company_name" name="companyName"/>
>
> </entity>  
>
>
> </entity>
>
> </document>
>
> </dataConfig>
> ```

Exception I am getting at delta import

```
/29/2017, 6:25:47 PM
ERROR true
JdbcDataSource
Ignoring Error when closing connection
java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@15196a0f is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:880)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:876)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:3111)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2366)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollbackNoChecks(ConnectionImpl.java:4738)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4630)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1515)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.closeConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:507)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.close(JdbcDataSource.java:492)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.closeEntityProcessorWrappers(DocBuilder.java:288)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.closeEntityProcessorWrappers(DocBuilder.java:290)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doDeltaImport(DataImporter.java:444)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:482)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
3/29/2017, 6

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: deltaQuery has no column to resolve to declared primary key pk='jobId'
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:270)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doDeltaImport(DataImporter.java:444)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:482)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: deltaQuery has no column to resolve to declared primary key pk='jobId'
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.findMatchingPkColumn(DocBuilder.java:755)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.collectDelta(DocBuilder.java:808)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.collectDelta(DocBuilder.java:789)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doDelta(DocBuilder.java:344)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:224)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you replace <'${dataimporter.delta.id}'> to ${dataimporter.delta.job_id}  and test.

deltaImportQuery : (Only used in delta-import) .There is a namespace ${dih.delta.**column-name**} which can be used in this query. e.g: select * from tbl where id=${dih.delta.id}   Solr1.4

as above line mentioned that we can only use column name in delta namespace.

reference:
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Configuration_in_data-config.xml

Comment: @Amit Patel Kindly test it and let me know whether your issue got resolved or not.I am curious to see your response

Comment: yeah its working properly . I missed that namespace , thanks